# Significance of symmetry of similar combinations

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

**Background:**

For a sequence of $n$ numbers, where each number can take a value in the range $[1;n]$, the amount of all possible combinations is given by:

$$
n^n
$$

For example, for $n = 3$ there are 27 possible combinations:

$$
\begin{matrix}
[1,1,1] & [2,1,1] & [3,1,1] & [1,2,1] & [2,2,1] & [3,2,1] & [1,3,1] & [2,3,1] & [3,3,1] \\
[1,1,2] & [2,1,2] & [3,1,2] & [1,2,2] & [2,2,2] & [3,2,2] & [1,3,2] & [2,3,2] & [3,3,2] \\
[1,1,3] & [2,1,3] & [3,1,3] & [1,2,3] & [2,2,3] & [3,2,3] & [1,3,3] & [2,3,3] & [3,3,3]
\end{matrix}
$$

Now to me some of them appear quite similar. For example, $[1,1,1]$ and $[2,2,2]$ are both combinations of a single value repeated $n$ times. Similarly, $[1,2,3]$ and $[3,2,1]$ contain the full range of possible values (a further distinction can be made for ordered and disordered combinations of all possible values). In general, this set of combinations can be mapped to a "reduced" set by assigning a new value to each integer based on the order in which it appears. In other words, the first integer, from left to right, in the combination will be mapped to, say, the letter $a$, whereas the second integer, if there is one, will be mapped to $b$, and so on. Some examples:

$$
\begin{align}
[2,3,1] &\to [a,b,c] \\
[1,2,2] &\to [a,b,b] \\
[3,2,1] &\to [a,b,c]
\end{align}
$$

This way, for $n = 3$, there are five reduced combinations:

$$
[a,a,a] \quad [a,b,b] \quad [a,b,a] \quad [a,a,b] \quad [a,b,c]
$$

And here is the whole reduced set:

$$
\begin{matrix}
[a,a,a] & [a,b,b] & [a,b,b] & [a,b,a] & [a,a,b] & [a,b,c] & [a,b,a] & [a,b,c] & [a,a,b] \\
[a,a,b] & [a,b,a] & [a,b,c] & [a,b,b] & [a,a,a] & [a,b,b] & [a,b,c] & [a,b,a] & [a,a,b] \\
[a,a,b] & [a,b,c] & [a,b,a] & [a,b,c] & [a,a,b] & [a,b,a] & [a,b,b] & [a,b,b] & [a,a,a]
\end{matrix}
$$

If I were to write down the indices of the repeated combinations, I would notice two things:

- There is a symmetry around the middle element (14th for $n=3$)
- The indices of the repeated reduced combinations form interesting patterns

To illustrate what I am talking about, here are some images (hopefully self explanatory):

[image: table of combinations]
[image: symmetry tree]
[image: symmetry plot]

**Questions:**

Have these patterns been studied? Are they of some mathematical significance? I would like to learn more about them, particularly I am interested in three things at the moment: (1) are these patterns natural or something I induced myself; (2) to what degree does the order matter, i.e. are these patterns preserved if the set of combinations is ordered differently; (3) is there a way to predict these patterns.

I tried to search for the indices in OEIS but I could not find anything substantial.